# "Add to cart" button stopped working when I moved my site to a test server on-line

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla, virtuemart

I have recently moved my site from a local server to a test server on-line. I noticed when I made the change, my "Add to cart" button stopped working.

also..

When a user logged into the site the login link would change to log out so that's not working either. I think this all has to do with something that I just cant seem to find.

I know if has something to do with conflicting javascript or Ajax. I really need to get this fixed please help.

Here is the link to the TEST site.

http://mackeyshotrods.com/test/store/rvca-detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact that your request origin is `http://mackeyshotrods.com` but your request is going to `http://**www.**mackeyshotrods.com`, which is not allowed by [HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). If you go to http://www.mackeyshotrods.com/test/store/rvca-detail the add to cart button will work, because the request is made from the same origin.

The variable that seems to be causing the issue is `window.vmSiteurl`, which is currently set to `"http://www.mackeyshotrods.com/test/"` but should be set to `"http://mackeyshotrods.com/test/"`. This is probably a setting in whatever the system you're using is.

Comment: How do I do this no one explains it???

Comment: @ijustchill I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: I changed my public $live_site = 'http://mackeyshotrods.com/test/'; Thank you for trying to explain this. Where else can I look to make this change? I also changed my VM URL to http://mackeyshotrods.com/test/ and still no fix?

Comment: @ijustchill I wouldn't know, I'm not a VirtueMart expert. Maybe it's a setting in your database?

Comment: I still don't know how to fix this but you figured out what was wrong.